# Auto expiration for task run using SCDF

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We are using SCDF 1.2.3.RELEASE (Local Server) for calling different task created using spring cloud task 1.2.2.RELEASE. In some cases, it is possible that a running task which has been created by SCDF may take time longer than expected or gets crash because of any reason. In such cases, we have seen that SCDF shows that task as running even though it has been crashed.

So does SCDF has any property(like expirationTime or anything like that) which we can set so that after that amount of time SCDF will consider it as a failed task and try to auto kill it and at the same time updates the underlying database accordingly.

Comment: Could you share a Task application sample that reproduces this problem? It is hard to troubleshoot just the description of the problem.

Comment: There is no specific example of that task but when is any issue in database connection or java runtime environment gets crashed we have seen that for that execution we get start time but no end time.